# How can I express the Riemann tensor of the 4-metric in terms of quantities derived from the 3-metric and the normal to it?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

I want an expression for the Riemann tensor of the four metric in terms of extrinsic curvature, normal, lie derivative of the normal, etc.
The first Einstein-Codacci eq. gives the Riemann tensor of the three metric in terms of the contracted Riemann four tensor and the extrinsic curvature. So this is not the one I want. 
Does anyone know a relation that I am looking for? And how to derive it?

Answer (score 1):

See this [reference](http://www.luth.obspm.fr/~luthier/gourgoulhon/fr/present_rec/pohang08-1.pdf)

The formula is on Page 11 (Codazzi Equation) (The definition of the metrics $\gamma$ is on page 7).